# Why can't we "subscribe" to some user's new questions?

Tags: feature-request

It would be a great feature if one could "subscribe" to the questions of any particular user. Some users ask good questions from your area of expertise, so you want to be notified when it happens.

Comment: What, like the [rss feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/255799) on the user page? (user feed link a the bottom right of the profile page)

Comment: @Oded you are always fast, I posted an answer about that and then found your comment posted 40 seconds before me :)

Comment: @Oded Is there an easy way to filter out just questions from an RSS feed?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I don't believe so. It would probably be easier through the API.

Comment: As Oded said, this is [possible with API](http://calculus7.org/2013/12/21/filtering-stackexchange-users/) and a userscript. There is StackEye on Stackapps, which is very close to what you want, but includes both answers and questions.

Comment: .. and here's a [link](http://stackapps.com/q/4454/25536) to StackEye; unfortunately it's Chrome-only at present.

Answer (score 1):

How about subscribing using RSS:

**https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/[user Id]**

Change the user id and then use any RSS feed app or the browser.

Comment: It is more of a workaround. Why not to make a system's feature.

Comment: Too noisy. Reading every comment that the user leaves somewhere quickly gets old (especially as comments are given without context). The feed does not filter for questions.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 true, I guess it would be nice if they allow some parameters to filter the feed. Something like `?type=q` or `?type=a`

Comment: @Graduate: what would that accomplish? How will that help bring better questions or answers to the site, that using the RSS feed cannot do now?